# Why does GRUB2 boot a different OS than the one i selected on startup?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a 1tb HDD and 256gb SSD with 3 different installations of Ubuntu installed.

The 256gb ssd has two installations of ubuntu, version 18.04 and 22.04 both of these installations can be chosen during the grub menu on startup, and they boot fine.

The 1tb ssd has a single installation of 18.04, it shows up on the grub menu, and I can select it, but it does not boot. Instead of booting, when it is selected, the installation of 22.04 from my ssd boots up.

I tried running update-grub, but this didn't fix the issue.

Below are images showing how my drives are setup, and a pastebin from the utility called "boot-repair":

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KTMsQXWJ7w/

```
boot-repair-4ppa200                                              [20221025_2033]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for /boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk search_fs_uuid
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    config script
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    search.fs_uuid 00e3c403-a8f9-4c9a-ac60-220b986df3ed root hd1,msdos1 
    set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
    
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => libparted MBR boot code is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the boot sector of sda1 
                       and looks at sector 325760 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img. core.img is at this location and looks for 
                       (,msdos1)/grub. It also embeds following components:
                       
                       modules
                       -------------------------------------------------------
                       fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
                       -------------------------------------------------------
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdc and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdc: /dev/sdc already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 3 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS CurrentSession on sdb2
OS#2:   Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on sda2
OS#3:   Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on sdb1

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti] from NVIDIA Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/vmlinuz-5.15.0-50-generic root=UUID=f6de26f5-db9e-41a1-9876-a7a731eaccd1 ro quiet splash
df -Th / : /dev/sdb2      ext4   46G  9.7G   34G  23% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: P1.30(4.6) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware seems EFI-compatible, but this installed-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sdb : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb2    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb7    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb1    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    not-far
sdb6    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   no-grubenv, update-grub,    not-far
sda3    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ok, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda6    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb7    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb1    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb6    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda6    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb7    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb1    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sdb
sdb6    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  fstab-has-goodBOOT, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda3    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda1    : is---sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda6    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x39e4afaf
      Boot    Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1  *        2048    2000895    1998848   976M 83 Linux
sda2        2000896   21532671   19531776   9.3G 83 Linux
sda3       21532672   41064447   19531776   9.3G 83 Linux
sda4       41066494 1953523711 1912457218 911.9G  5 Extended
sda5       41066496   56692735   15626240   7.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
sda6       56694784 1953523711 1896828928 904.5G 83 Linux
Disk sdb: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xb3406350
      Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sdb1            2048  97658879  97656832  46.6G 83 Linux
sdb2        97658880 195315129  97656250  46.6G 83 Linux
sdb3       195317758 500117503 304799746 145.3G  5 Extended
sdb5       195317760 210943999  15626240   7.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
sdb6       210946048 355518463 144572416  68.9G 83 Linux
sdb7       355520512 500117503 144596992  68.9G 83 Linux
Disk sdc: 14.9 GiB, 16000221184 bytes, 31250432 sectors
Disk identifier: 9240A165-D190-4AB6-8A10-46DC207B42EE
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdc1       64  7465119  7465056  3.6G Microsoft basic data
sdc2  7465120  7473615     8496  4.1M EFI System
sdc3  7473616  7474215      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdc4  7475200 31250368 23775169 11.3G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA Hitachi HDT72101:;
1:1049kB:1024MB:1023MB:ext4::boot;
2:1024MB:11.0GB:10.0GB:ext4::;
3:11.0GB:21.0GB:10.0GB:ext4::;
4:21.0GB:1000GB:979GB:::;
5:21.0GB:29.0GB:8001MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
6:29.0GB:1000GB:971GB:ext4::;
sdb:256GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA Samsung SSD 840:;
1:1049kB:50.0GB:50.0GB:ext4::;
2:50.0GB:100GB:50.0GB:ext4::;
3:100GB:256GB:156GB:::;
5:100GB:108GB:8001MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
6:108GB:182GB:74.0GB:ext4::;
7:182GB:256GB:74.0GB:ext4::;
sdc:16.0GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:PNY USB 3.0 FD:;
1:32.8kB:3822MB:3822MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:3822MB:3826MB:4350kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:3826MB:3827MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:3827MB:16.0GB:12.2GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                
├─sda1 ext4     096a39d4-fc8e-44a8-a024-4174a9e5cc6e 39e4afaf-01                          Boot                     
├─sda2 ext4     36d6b562-b1ae-4f12-9125-71d82b6c0cb1 39e4afaf-02                          Admin 1                  
├─sda3 ext4     7e1cae48-6e0d-49cc-ae0f-5473dfe5dab0 39e4afaf-03                          Admin 2                  
├─sda4                                               39e4afaf-04                                                   
├─sda5 swap     37290975-5afc-4df0-bbf6-e37c2a866b8e 39e4afaf-05                                                   
└─sda6 ext4     717254bc-e19c-4fe6-a9a4-1ed6f52b5f45 39e4afaf-06                                                   
sdb                                                                                                                
├─sdb1 ext4     00e3c403-a8f9-4c9a-ac60-220b986df3ed b3406350-01                          WebDev1                  
├─sdb2 ext4     f6de26f5-db9e-41a1-9876-a7a731eaccd1 b3406350-02                                                   
├─sdb3                                               b3406350-03                                                   
├─sdb5 swap     b820b73a-2c7f-43f0-a28c-dda197aa2789 b3406350-05                                                   
├─sdb6 ext4     900b666c-d069-4e62-9fcf-33a37f5780e4 b3406350-06                          Sys Img Zipd             
└─sdb7 ext4     96ff5161-bf69-4304-ad03-035e7b572ef7 b3406350-07                          Sys Img PreZip           
sdc    iso9660  2022-08-10-16-21-45-00                                                    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS amd64 
├─sdc1 iso9660  2022-08-10-16-21-45-00               9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a11-46dc207b42ee Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdc2 vfat     8D6C-A9F8                            9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a12-46dc207b42ee ESP                      Appended2
├─sdc3                                               9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a13-46dc207b42ee                          Gap1
└─sdc4 ext4     eac31582-53ae-4cb9-a895-c86869e919de 20d06f91-b06c-3740-a315-e3fbcb88e4ed writable                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                      661.4M  23% /boot
/dev/sda2                        3.3G  59% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3                        8.6G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sda6                        844G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda6
/dev/sdb1                       19.5G  52% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1
/dev/sdb2                       33.6G  21% /
/dev/sdb2[/usr/share/hunspell]  33.6G  21% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
/dev/sdb6                       39.8G  36% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb6
/dev/sdb7                       63.9G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb7
/dev/sdc1                           0 100% /media/laraki/Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS amd64
/dev/sdc4                       10.5G   0% /media/laraki/writable

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1                      ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda2                      ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda3                      ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda6                      ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1                      ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb2                      ext4            rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdb2[/usr/share/hunspell] ext4            ro,noexec,noatime,errors=remount-ro
/dev/sdb6                      ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb7                      ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdc1                      iso9660         ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmode=500,fmode=400,iocharset=utf8
/dev/sdc4                      ext4            rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=remount-ro

======================== sda1/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =========================

Ubuntu   f6de26f5-db9e-41a1-9876-a7a731eaccd1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-52-generic   f6de26f5-db9e-41a1-9876-a7a731eaccd1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-50-generic   f6de26f5-db9e-41a1-9876-a7a731eaccd1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-51-generic   f6de26f5-db9e-41a1-9876-a7a731eaccd1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-46-generic   f6de26f5-db9e-41a1-9876-a7a731eaccd1
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (18.04) (on sda2)   36d6b562-b1ae-4f12-9125-71d82b6c0cb1
Ubuntu (on sda2)   36d6b562-b1ae-4f12-9125-71d82b6c0cb1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-52-generic (on sda2)   36d6b562-b1ae-4f12-9125-71d82b6c0cb1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-50-generic (on sda2)   36d6b562-b1ae-4f12-9125-71d82b6c0cb1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-51-generic (on sda2)   36d6b562-b1ae-4f12-9125-71d82b6c0cb1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-46-generic (on sda2)   36d6b562-b1ae-4f12-9125-71d82b6c0cb1
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (18.04) (on sdb1)   00e3c403-a8f9-4c9a-ac60-220b986df3ed
Ubuntu (on sdb1)   00e3c403-a8f9-4c9a-ac60-220b986df3ed
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-128-generic (on sdb1)   00e3c403-a8f9-4c9a-ac60-220b986df3ed
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-86-generic (on sdb1)   00e3c403-a8f9-4c9a-ac60-220b986df3ed
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0.206081390 = 0.221278208    grub/grub.cfg                                  1
   0.155357361 = 0.166813696    grub/i386-pc/core.img                          1
   0.222663879 = 0.239083520    vmlinuz                                        2
   0.621093750 = 0.666894336    vmlinuz-5.15.0-50-generic                      2
   0.222663879 = 0.239083520    vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic                      2
   0.196994781 = 0.211521536    vmlinuz-5.3.0-46-generic                       1
   0.236061096 = 0.253468672    vmlinuz-5.3.0-51-generic                       1
   0.621093750 = 0.666894336    vmlinuz.old                                    2
   0.458393097 = 0.492195840    initrd.img                                     2
   0.360347748 = 0.386920448    initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic                   2
   0.458393097 = 0.492195840    initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic                   2
   0.420207977 = 0.451194880    initrd.img-5.3.0-46-generic                    1
   0.342082977 = 0.367308800    initrd.img-5.3.0-51-generic                    1
   0.360347748 = 0.386920448    initrd.img.old                                 2

========================== sda2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=36d6b562-b1ae-4f12-9125-71d82b6c0cb1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=096a39d4-fc8e-44a8-a024-4174a9e5cc6e /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=37290975-5afc-4df0-bbf6-e37c2a866b8e none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/e2788e65-6ed5-454d-8940-1e607d50da06 /mnt/e2788e65-6ed5-454d-8940-1e607d50da06 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

======================= sda2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

===================== sda2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12693 Nov 10  2019 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11298 Nov 10  2019 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Nov 10  2019 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1418 Nov 10  2019 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Nov 10  2019 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Nov 10  2019 41_custom

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   00e3c403-a8f9-4c9a-ac60-220b986df3ed
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-128-generic   00e3c403-a8f9-4c9a-ac60-220b986df3ed
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-86-generic   00e3c403-a8f9-4c9a-ac60-220b986df3ed
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (18.04) (on sda2)   36d6b562-b1ae-4f12-9125-71d82b6c0cb1
Ubuntu (on sda2)   36d6b562-b1ae-4f12-9125-71d82b6c0cb1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-50-generic (on sda2)   36d6b562-b1ae-4f12-9125-71d82b6c0cb1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-43-generic (on sda2)   36d6b562-b1ae-4f12-9125-71d82b6c0cb1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-51-generic (on sda2)   36d6b562-b1ae-4f12-9125-71d82b6c0cb1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-46-generic (on sda2)   36d6b562-b1ae-4f12-9125-71d82b6c0cb1
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (22.04) (on sdb2)   f6de26f5-db9e-41a1-9876-a7a731eaccd1
Ubuntu (on sdb2)   f6de26f5-db9e-41a1-9876-a7a731eaccd1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-50-generic (on sdb2)   f6de26f5-db9e-41a1-9876-a7a731eaccd1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-43-generic (on sdb2)   f6de26f5-db9e-41a1-9876-a7a731eaccd1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-51-generic (on sdb2)   f6de26f5-db9e-41a1-9876-a7a731eaccd1
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-46-generic (on sdb2)   f6de26f5-db9e-41a1-9876-a7a731eaccd1
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sdb1/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=00e3c403-a8f9-4c9a-ac60-220b986df3ed /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=37290975-5afc-4df0-bbf6-e37c2a866b8e none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=b820b73a-2c7f-43f0-a28c-dda197aa2789 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/c65942e2-2186-4114-804d-71585eaee7f4 /mnt/c65942e2-2186-4114-804d-71585eaee7f4 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

======================= sdb1/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=6
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=30
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  20.243171692 = 21.735940096   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             4
  12.285900116 = 13.191884800   boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
   9.136188507 = 9.809907712    boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-128-generic                 1
   3.814472198 = 4.095758336    boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-86-generic                  2
   9.136188507 = 9.809907712    vmlinuz                                        1
   3.814472198 = 4.095758336    vmlinuz.old                                    2
   9.450206757 = 10.147082240   boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-128-generic              1
   9.208023071 = 9.887039488    boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-86-generic               5
   9.450206757 = 10.147082240   initrd.img                                     1
   9.208023071 = 9.887039488    initrd.img.old                                 5

===================== sdb1: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12808 Aug 24  2020 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11298 Nov 10  2019 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Nov 10  2019 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1418 Nov 10  2019 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Nov 10  2019 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Nov 10  2019 41_custom

========================== sdb2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=f6de26f5-db9e-41a1-9876-a7a731eaccd1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=096a39d4-fc8e-44a8-a024-4174a9e5cc6e /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=37290975-5afc-4df0-bbf6-e37c2a866b8e none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=b820b73a-2c7f-43f0-a28c-dda197aa2789 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sdb2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

===================== sdb2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 15  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Apr 15  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 Apr 15  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 15  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 15  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 19  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 15  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15  2022 41_custom

=========================== sdb2/etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ===========================

#! /bin/sh
# SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
set -e
[ -d ${pkgdatadir:?} ]
# shellcheck source=/dev/null
. "$pkgdatadir/grub-mkconfig_lib"
if [ -f /var/lib/fwupd/uefi_capsule.conf ] &&
   ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/fwupd-*-0abba7dc-e516-4167-bbf5-4d9d1c739416 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
      . /var/lib/fwupd/uefi_capsule.conf
      if [ "${EFI_PATH}" != "" ] && [ "${ESP}" != "" ]; then
      echo "Adding Linux Firmware Updater entry" >&2
cat << EOF
menuentry 'Linux Firmware Updater' \$menuentry_id_option 'fwupd' {
EOF
      ${grub_probe:?}
      prepare_grub_to_access_device '`${grub_probe} --target=device \${ESP}` | sed -e "s/^/\t/"'
cat << EOF
    chainloader ${EFI_PATH}
}
EOF
      fi
fi



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub2 of
sdb1 into the MBR of sdb.
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

 Please use this software in a live-session (live-CD or live-USB). This will enable this feature.

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sdb (ATA Samsung SSD 840) disk!
```

https://postimg.cc/gallery/gXNT8v1/3fb67480

Comment: You seem to have a newer UEFI based system but old BIOS boot and very old MBR partitioning. Even if you insist on BIOS boot, better to use gpt, but then need a bios_grub partition. It looks like you have the same /boot partition in two installs. You cannot share a /boot partition. You also have installed grub to PBR or Boot Sector of partitions. It should only be installed to MBR for BIOS boot. With PBR, it has to use blocklists which are unreliable and you still have to have another grub to chain load into it.

Comment: Thank you for all of that information, I configured this myself with minimal research to be honest, it worked as intended for a while so I just assumed everything was good to go. What would your suggestion be for an optimal fix? I do need to retain the ability to create logical partitions as I've got limited drive space and need a large number of partitions. And would prefer to resolve without having to do fresh installs if it's possible.

Comment: You should only need one grub to boot all installs. I would install the grub of your main working install into MBR of sda. You can install another grub into sdb. Part of issue may be that major update to grub in other installs my install grub overwriting the one your want. But then you should just boot main install and reinstall grub from there. Better to manage yourself, see this: How to: Create a Customized GRUB2 Screen that is Maintenance Free.- Cavsfan
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen
& http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205 Jump to end latest.

Comment: So just to make sure I follow you. I should be able to install GRUB onto dev/sda1 from my main ubuntu installation. I should be able to then use the guide you linked to customize it. And I should be able to/need to delete all other installations of GRUB, and that will allow me to retain the ability to boot into all 3 of my operating systems on startup. Or am I missing something?

Comment: At this point, I've tried running grub-install /dev/sda and update-grub from both of my two working OS installs in the hope that on restart, the non-working install would be able to boot. But in both cases, when selecting the non-working install, the system booted into the installation of 22.04  ... I'm not sure if this means that somehow GRUB has become confused about the location of the BOOT_IMAGE for that broken install.

Comment: If two installs share /boot, only one will normally work.

Comment: Say if I made a new partition for /boot for the OS that no longer works, is there a way to reinstall or copy it's /boot information over from a different OS?

Comment: Probably easier to remove mount of /boot in fstab, and reinstall kernel & grub. Boot-Repair may make that easier. If LVM install, you may need /boot as separate partition. Are all installs in same boot mode, or all UEFI or all BIOS? You cannot mix and use grub to boot. Only from UEFI menu then could you boot. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I ended up reinstalling everything using efi instead of legacy boot, and as it turns out the benefits of this outweigh having to start over. So thank you oldfred for that tip.